# How to expose kafka for external access after build kafka cluster on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I build kafka cluster on kubernetes following this guilde https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/statefulsets/kafka, it works well for sending/producing message from kubernetes. when I try to expose the kafka cluster using NodePort as follows, kafka clients try to consumer/produce the message from the address ***10.xx.xx.xx:30092***

will be failed:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-nodeport
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    nodePort: 30092
    name: server
  selector:
    app: kafka
```

Why that happened and How to expose the kafka service?

Comment: What error are you getting? Btw did you try accessing via `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`?

Comment: when try to send message to NodeIP:NodePort, the client will raise error:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 33 record(s) for test-0: 1502 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time.

Answer (score 1):

The `Kafka Statefulsets` require headless service for accessing the brokers. You can change the headless service to Type=NodePort and setting the `externalTrafficPolicy=Local`. This bypasses the internal load balancing of a Service and traffic destined to a specific node on that node port will only work if a Kafka pod is on that node.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-nodeport
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    nodePort: 30092
    name: server
  selector:
    app: kafka
```

For example, we have two nodes nodeA and nodeB, nodeB is running a kafka pod. nodeA:30092 will not connect but nodeB:30092 will connect to the kafka pod running on nodeB.

Hope this helps.

Comment: try it, but it doesn' t  work when access nodeB:30092 from the machine outside of kubernetes

Comment: As we have set the `externalTrafficPolicy=Local` you can access a pod from nodeIP on which the port resides (not from all the node IP's). The reason to set externalTrafficPolicy=Local is that kafka needs headless service which turns off the internal load balancer of k8s, but you can not expose headless service using Nodeport

Answer (score 1):

You have to do two things :

1) create either a service resource of type NodePort (like you did) or an Ingress resource.

2) Set the two properties below in Kafka :
`ADVERTISED_HOST` and `ADVERTISED_PORT`.

Kafka will register to Zookeeper with the ip adress of the node, inside containers network it's the internal ip adress that it used so we have to set thoses properties to tell Kafka to register them instead.

Hopes that's help!